# ApiResponses is confusing Swagger-UI output to not find the "type"

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am not really a java developer (I was one 15 years ago) but I am trying to freshen my knowledge to be more valuable in those projects.  I am attempting to incorporate swagger-ui into a basic rest springboot app.  I am getting the following error:

> Unknown Type: CustomerVisit

I have the following controller defined:

```
package controller;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;


@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RestController
public class ScenarioController {

    @Autowired
    ScenarioService scenarioService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "scenario/{scenarioIdStr}", method = GET)
    @ApiResponses(value={
        @ApiResponse(responseCode="200", description="request accepted, scenario returned", content=@Content(schema=@Schema(type="CustomerVisit"))),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode="202", description="request accepted, no scenario available to return"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode="400", description="request not accepted, invalid input")
    })
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCustomerVisitByScenarioId(@PathVariable String scenarioIdStr) {

        try {
            int scenarioId = Integer.valueOf(scenarioIdStr);
            List<CustomerVisit> customerList = scenarioService.getScenarioById(scenarioId);

            if (customerList.size() > 0) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(customerList, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(customerList, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>( "Scenario ID must be integer.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

and the CustomerVisit bean as

```
package bean;
    
@Schema(name="CustomerVisit", description="A model of a customer")
public class CustomerVisit {
  
  public CustomerVisit(/* cut */) {
     /* cut - constructing class */      
  }

  /* cut getters */
}
```

The swagger-ui comes up and for other methods where I am not trying to provide `ApiResponses` in the documentation everything works.  Once I add the ApiResponses things start to fall apart.  IF i do not add the `@Content` annotation the ui describes the response types as `{}`.  If I add the name of the type as tagged in the bean - it says the type is unknown.  I haven't been able to find documentation to guide me on this was hoping to get a nudge in the right direction.

There look to be answers for older versions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update working but ugly approach

1. added static class that extends ArrayList
2. expose that

such that

```
public static class CustomerVisitList extends ArrayList<CustomerVisit> {}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "scenario/{scenarioIdStr}", method = GET)
@ApiResponses(value={
        @ApiResponse(responseCode="200", description="request accepted, scenario returned", content=@Content(schema=@Schema(implementation = CustomerVisitList.class))),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode="202", description="request accepted, no scenario available to return"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode="400", description="request not accepted, invalid input")
 })
```

Is there a better way?

---

This seems to be a step in the right direction (**it is not right**) - but it should really return a list back:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "scenario/{scenarioIdStr}", method = GET)
@ApiResponses(value={
    @ApiResponse(responseCode="200", description="request accepted, scenario returned", content=@Content(schema=@Schema(implementation = CustomerVisit.class))),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode="202", description="request accepted, no scenario available to return"),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode="400", description="request not accepted, invalid input")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ApiResponses(
value = {
    @ApiResponse(
      content = {
        @Content(
          mediaType = "application/json",
          array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = Product.class)))
      })
  })
@GetMapping("/products")
public List<Product> getProductsList() {
    return productService.getProductsList();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).